# meaning of gradient vector

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

If the gradient vector of a function is (1 1) does that imply that increasing x and y values by the same magnitude will lead to the greatest increase in z? considering z=f(x,y). At the same time, if the gradient vector is (2 1) then we should increase x by twice the magnitude of y to result in the greatest increase in z.

Comment: Correct. If you are unsure, play with a simple function such as $z=x^2+y^2$, where you know that it should increase in the radial direction.

Comment: That is correct. To understand this, suppose we have a function $f(x,y)$ and we look at the level sets (sets of the form $f(x,y)=c$ for some constant $c$). In "nice" situations, these will give smooth curves in the $x-y$ plane. Along the curve, $f$ isn't changing at all (it's constantly $c$ on the curve). Still in the "nice" situation, the direction of greatest increase will be perpendicular to that curve, which is where the gradient points. Andrei's example is a good one to use with this. Level sets are circle, the gradient is the outward normal to that circle.

Comment: Analogous statements hold in higher dimensions, too. If we have a function $f(x,y,z)$, then level sets $f(x,y,z)=c$ will (still in the "nice" situation) look like $2d$ surfaces in three dimensional space. The function doesn't change along the surface, and it changes the fastest perpendicular to the surface, which is where the gradient points.